# I'm using comp function using which I want to sort an array but for one test case it is failing

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

You are given an array of size **N**. Rearrange the given array in place such that all the negative numbers occur before all non-negative numbers. (Maintain the order of all -ve and non-negative numbers as given in the original array).

```
N = 4
Arr[] = {-3, 1, 0, -2}
output= -3 -2 1 0
```

#### I have to complete the function  Rearrange()  so I have done this-

#### Question link=[question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/arranging-the-array1131/1)     this code fails for test case 10

```
static bool comp(int a, int b) { return (a < 0 && b >= 0); }

void Rearrange(int arr[], int n) { sort(arr, arr + n, comp); }
```

- test case 10 =

  91

  263 22 270 343 -101 -398 -154 193 157 168 -166 292 142 -104 310 294 1 -449 223 -216 -33 394 -197 233 329 -439 -423 -317 443 -174 241 288 167 117 -360 -12 86 -62 109 -15 267 76 296 388 -132 -342 400 240 -46 -163 436 288 434 384 -351 305 -199 -158 427 169 288 -406 305 295 264 129 423 -285 -261 -46 -200 -1 453 404 351 420 68 -433 -82 -131 -71 -66 -42 333 17 34 -393 -262 54 342 -53

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `std::stable_sort`?

Comment: Look like another competitive coding site to me, just note they will not teach you how to use C++ in a good way. For example you pass `int[]` and a seperate `int n` to Rearrange, in C++ it is more common to use `std::vector<int>&` for that (or std::array).

Comment: Wrong algorithm.  You should be using [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? That would help immensely. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function doesn't guarantee stability, you are looking for [`std::stable_partiton`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), which does while also achieving: *(Maintain the order of all -ve and non-negative numbers as given in the original array)*:

```
void Rearrange(int arr[], int n) {
    std::stable_partition(arr, arr + n, [](int x){return x < 0;});
}
```

[`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) won't work as it won't be able to achieve *(Maintain the order of all -ve and non-negative numbers as given in the original array*) as it will try to sort the non-equivalent elements.

> The order of equivalent elements is guaranteed to be preserved.